# email read from EWS (exchange web service) server cannot process this request error c#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, exchangewebservices

I have a task where i need to check the emails delivered to my mailbox and read them ,based on subject i have to do some task. But for demo purpose I have put only the basic functionality of just updating the email read status

The basic connection and creating service object everything is fine:

///////////

```
    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(securelyStoredEmail, securelyStoredPassword);

    ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
_service.Credentials = credentials;

    _service.AutodiscoverUrl("User1@contoso.com");
```

/////////////////////////
Here Everything works fine. However I will invoke the below method for every 60s using observable event of reactive linq. THis is to go and poll the my emailbox and read 100 emails for every 60 seconds. 
Everything works fine till sometime. Sometimes when the control reaches the line of code inside parallel.foreach loop, it shows error message like 'server cannot process this request now. Please try later' something like this. THis error comes exactly at the line

```
var email = EmailMessage.Bind(_service, findItemsResult.Id, emailProps);
```

so for every 60 seconds, i will get this error sometimes.sometimes it works fine. 
Below is the method which is executed for every 60seconds. Its like i try to read the emails from "myaccount.com" for every 60s and i vil get the error 'server cannot process'.

```
internal void GetEmailsFrommymailbox()
{ 

try
{

var view = new ItemView(100);
var userMailbox = new Mailbox(userMailbox);
var folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, userMailbox);
SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And,
new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));



var findResults = _service.FindItems(folderId, sf, view);
var emailProps = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent, ItemSchema.Body,
ItemSchema.InternetMessageHeaders);

Parallel.ForEach(findResults, findItemsResult =>
{


///////////// this is the line where i get error////////

    var email = EmailMessage.Bind(_service, findItemsResult.Id, emailProps);

//// above is the place where i get error

var emailMatching = email;
try
{
email.IsRead = true;
email.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);

}
catch (Exception emailreadFromBccException)
{
Logger.Warn(emailreadFromBccException + " Unable to update email read status");
}


});
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getting that error because you being throttled https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945066%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx and your being throttled because you code isn't very efficient.

Instead of doing

Parallel.ForEach(findResults, findItemsResult =>
{

///////////// this is the line where i get error////////

```
var email = EmailMessage.Bind(_service, findItemsResult.Id, emailProps);
```

You should use LoadPropertiesFromItems http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2010/03/16/loading-properties-for-multiple-items-with-one-call-to-exchange-web-services.aspx . Which will reduce the number of call you need to make to the server.

I would also suggest you use Streaming notification https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh312849%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 which will mean you won't need to poll the server every 60 seconds and just take an action when a new item arrives.

Cheers
Glen